# php scraper scripts need to be changed

Tags: php

this script harvests links out of a seed url and only prints them in command shell (or browser) rather than saving elsewhere. I want the script to store any outputs in .txt file within the folder where the script resides. I need suggestions what could be the efficient way to do that. Please give me hints.

```
<?php

# Initialization
include("LIB_http.php");                        // http library
include("LIB_parse.php");                       // parse library
include("LIB_resolve_addresses.php");           // address resolution library
include("LIB_exclusion_list.php");              // list of excluded keywords
include("LIB_simple_spider.php");               // spider routines used by this app.


set_time_limit(3600);                           // Don't let PHP timeout

$SEED_URL        = "http://www.schrenk.com";    // First URL spider downloads
$MAX_PENETRATION = 1;                           // Set spider penetration depth
$FETCH_DELAY     = 1;                           // Wait one second between page fetches
$ALLOW_OFFISTE   = false;                        // Don't allow spider to roam from the SEED_URL's domain
$spider_array = array();

# Get links from $SEED_URL
echo "Harvesting Seed URL    \n"; 
$temp_link_array = harvest_links($SEED_URL);
$spider_array = archive_links($spider_array, 0, $temp_link_array);

# Spider links in remaining penetration levels
for($penetration_level=1; $penetration_level<=$MAX_PENETRATION; $penetration_level++)
    {
    $previous_level = $penetration_level - 1;
    for($xx=0; $xx<count($spider_array[$previous_level]); $xx++)
        {
        unset($temp_link_array);
        $temp_link_array = harvest_links($spider_array[$previous_level][$xx]);
        echo "Level=$penetration_level, xx=$xx of ".count($spider_array[$previous_level])." <br>\n"; 
        $spider_array = archive_links($spider_array, $penetration_level, $temp_link_array);
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Your question is then "how do I save a string to a file?" -> `file_put_contents()` is your friend [and google as well].

Comment: Search for Ob_Start() and file_put_contents() and tell me if it serves what you want, and I give an example

Comment: # Vinicius file_put_contents() is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use file_put_contents PHP function with enable append file flag.

```
$file = 'file_name.txt';

file_put_contents($file, $text_to_write_to_file, FILE_APPEND);
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend first creating a variable to store the output in the script.  So at the top (under the `$spider_array=array()` ) add:

```
$output = "";
```

The change all the lines with `echo`  to be `$output .=`

This will store all the content sent to the screen or the browser into the `$output` variable.

Now at the bottom of the script, after everything has been scraped and the spider is finished, save the output to a file:

```
$filename = date('Y_m_d_H_i_s') . '.txt';
$filepath = dirname(__FILE__);
file_put_contents($filepath . '/' . $filename, $output);
```

This should save the output in a file within the same folder as the script with a date/time file name.  (This code was written using examples from php.net, exact implementation may need a bit of debugging, but this should get you close enough.